# How to convert byte array to map[string,string] in golang

Tags: go, hashmap, arrays

I want to convert byte array to map[string,string] using golang. I tried this:

```
var byte := json.Marshal(input)
var map := make(map[string]string *byte) // NOT WORKING
```

if byte holds value like {\"hello\":\"world\",...}
How to create the map from byte array

Please help.

Comment: The code you posted makes not much sense (it has multiple compilation errors). Please explain in greater detail what you want (edit the question).

Comment: What is a `map[string]string *byte` supposed to be? Your syntax has too many errors to try and guess.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go to further understand how to do what you want

Comment: There's no such thing as map[string,string].

Answer (score 19):

You probably want to do something like

```
m := make(map[string]string)
err := json.Unmarshal(input, &m)
```

This creates a new map[string]string and unmarshals a byte array into it.